# ¿Cómo crear este arreglo?

Tags: c

He estado pensando en como resolver este ejercicio pero no se me ocurre alguna forma ¿podrían ayudarme a hacer el codigo para resolver este ejercicio?

> Una compañía eléctrica factura los 200 primeros kWh a 1,0 €/kWh, los siguientes 300 kWh a 0,8 € y los restantes a 0,5 €.
>
> Escribir un programa que pida los nombres y los consumos de n clientes y a continuación muestre el nombre del cliente con mayor consumo y el importe de su factura.
>
> Como el objetivo final es mostrar los datos de un solo cliente, no es necesario utilizar vectores.

El programa debe incluir una función `double Cargo(int consumo)` que reciba un consumo en kWh y devuelva la correspondiente cantidad de dinero a cargar.

Comment: Este tipo de preguntas no son bien recibidas sin, al menos, mostrar el trabajo que has realizado hasta ahora. Una discusión al respecto: [Preguntas de “¡Hacedme el ejercicio que me han mandado!”](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/q/588/23371).

Comment: Basicamente le estas pidiendo que te hagas los ejercicios de clase, si reformularas la pregunta a lo mejor pues bueno poniendo una duda sobre aquello que no sabes resolver no todo el ejercicio, pero abajo veo que te lo han resuelto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La operación matemática, usa lógica jaja, son clientes, vamos, ¿qué necesitamos? enteros, no creo que pueda ser un cliente y medio:

```
int clientes = 100; // entero de cuantos clientes son int = entero
```

Pedir nombres de clientes, ocupamos `malloc` para reservar memoria y scanf para comar los datos, y podemos ocupar structuras (struct) o char vector tipo array (`[]`)

`%s` = string (cadena)
`%i` = int (entero)
`%f` = float (flotante/decimal 1.x)

```
struct clientes_nombres {
     tipodevalor (* apuntador en caso de char si es necesario);
     otro valor
} variable = {
     datos de valores;
}
```

Array con char:

```
char nombres[] = {"valor1", "valor2"}
```

Añadir un elemento a un array tipo char:

```
char valores[ENTERO_DE_MAXIMO_DE_VALORES];
valores[LUGAR] = ??
```

Es lo necesario, pero te recomiendo aprender con guías, yo aprendía con [elrincondelc.com](https://elrincondelc.com)